# Sending Data Between Node And HTML

Tags: node.js, html, express, chart.js

Apologies in advanced if this question seems silly. Node, JS and HTML are very new to me.

Currently I have a simple Express Node Server. It fetches data periodically and stores the results in SQL.

I also have a html page in my routes named graph.html.
On this page I'm using Chart.js

I would like to know the simplest way for my html page to request plot data from my node application when the page first loads.

Edit: I seem to be getting a lot of down votes for this question. I will happily accept advice on how to improve my question

Comment: You're getting downvotes because you don't supply us any structure or code to work with. We have to guess how you structured your applications. Questions with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will be easier to solve for others! Another reason could be that users think you didn't do any research, which would be a reason for downvoting, as hovering over the downvote arrow shows that specific reason.

Comment: Thankyou for the feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all:**
Please provide more information about your client's webpage and your node application! There are different ways to get what you want. On the one hand you can use template engines in your node application to pass data to your client webpage.

**Frontend:**

On the other hand you can do it by simply do an ajax request when loading the webpage. I recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for your webpage. Besides a lot of helpful features for developing your webpage, it provides some simple ajax-functionalities to easily set the xhr headers and manage the asynchronity.

If you managed to setup your webpage so far, so that you can use jQuery try this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", // specify you request type here (e.g. "POST", "PUT", etc.)
    url: "/theURL" // modify the url according to your application logic
}).done(function(yourData) {
    // work with your data
});
```

**Backend:**

Since I don't know how you setup your node application, I can't tell you more about this side. Assuming that you are using the [express](https://expressjs.com/) server framework:

```js
    // here goes the specified request type from above (e.g. app.post, app.put, etc.)
    app.get('/theURL', function(req, res) {
        var data;
        // Get your data from your database
        res.json(data);
    });
```